# Django Search Bar Autocomplete is not populating at all

Tags: django, search, autocomplete, searchbar, jsonresponse

I'm looking to use autocomplete to show the items already populated in the 'ComicInputs' model filed named 'Title'. It will not work after trying a few different options.
I'm using a JsonResponse in this version.

**Models.py**

```
class ComicInput(models.Model):
        Title = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='', blank=False, help_text="Comic Book title")
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.http import JsonResponse


@require_GET
def get_titles(request):
    if 'term' in request.GET:
        qs = ComicInput.objects.filter(Title__icontains=request.GET.get('term'))
        titles = list(qs.values_list('Title', flat=True))
        return JsonResponse(titles, safe=False)
    return render(request, 'app/layout.html')
```

**Urls.py**

```
path('layout/get_titles/', views.get_titles, name='get_titles')
```

layout.html

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'app/content/bootstrap.min.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'app/content/site.css' %}" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'app/scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js' %}"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#search").autocomplete({
                source: '{% url 'get_titles' %}',
                minLength: 2
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>

<form action="{% url 'search_page' %}" method="get" class="search-bar"  style="width: 200px; height: 30px;font-size: small; align: top;" >
                            <input type="search"  id ="search" name="search" pattern=".*\S.*" value="Search Collections by Title" onFocus="this.value=''" required>

                            <button class="search-btn" type="submit" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                                <span>&#x1F50D;</span>
                            </button>
                        </form>
```